# How to reduce very large set of gz files (without file extension) to a few files?

Tags: bash

I have 800K gz files that have hex file names like this:

> 000e31ec-bb1b-42af-80c9-97635ae75cb2

They do not have `.gz` extension but are definitely gz files:

```
017-06-14/000e31ec-bb1b-42af-80c9-97635ae75cb2: gzip compressed data, was "000e31ec-bb1b-42af-80c9-97635ae75cb2", last modified: Tue Jun 13 06:22:33 2017, max compression
```

I want to reduce these 800K files to something that won't break my Spark cluster, say 800 files. Apparently zcat won't work directly on the files because they don't have the `.gz` extension. Any thoughts?